# Авторизация на сайте через бот телеграм php

Tags: php, telegram-bot

В php новичок в данный момент стоит задача: есть бот телеграм на php кот. привязан к сайту в бот е при нажатии /start следующим шагом идет регистрация как сделать чтобы регистрация происходила автоматчески на первом шаге тоесть при нажатии старт

```
    $bot->command('start', function ($message) use ($bot) {
        $format = null;
        $params = getParams($message->getText());
        $id = $message->getChat()->getId();
        $code = isset($params[1]) ? $params[1] : null;
        $isRef = strpos($code, 'ef')  != false; // check 'ref'
        $ref = null;
        if($isRef)
        {
            $ref = substr($code, 3);
        }
        $user = GetUserByChatId($id, $ref);
        //запрос с кодом?
        if (!is_null($code) && $code != 'menu' && !$isRef) {
            $json = TelegramConnect($code, $id);
            $keyboard = Keyboards::Get('start_user');
            $answer = $json['message'];
        } else {
            if (is_null($user)) {
                $format = 'MarkdownV2';
                $answer = 'Пишет что нужно авторизироваться';
                $answer = FormatMarkdownV2($answer);
                $keyboard = Keyboards::Get('start_anonymous');
            } else {
                $answer = 'ответ';
                $keyboard = Keyboards::Get('start_user');
            }
        }
        // $answer .= 'You code: ' . $code . "\n";
        // $answer .= 'You telegramm_id: ' . $message->getChat()->getId();
        $bot->sendMessage($id, $answer, $format, false, null, $keyboard);
    });

    $bot->callbackQuery(function ($callbackQuery) use ($bot) {
        $chatId = $callbackQuery->getMessage()->getChat()->getId();
        $message = $callbackQuery->getMessage();
        $user = GetUserByChatId($chatId);
        $data = $callbackQuery->getData();
        if (CallBacks::Exists($data) != -1) {
            CallBacks::Doo($data, [
                'bot' => $bot,
                'chat_id' => $chatId,
                'user' => $user,
                'message' => $message,
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: если новичек, зачем сразу лезешь в дебри?

Comment: Не таки уже и дебри. Я попросил ответить по существу.  А не спросил совета куда мне лезть или не лезить

Comment: по-существу - это объяснить несколько разделов php.net?

Comment: Можно спросит ещё у вас как оно сразу рождаться гением?

Comment: Ну так и делать, отлавливать start далее сверять если пользователь не зарегистрирован то регистрируем, если уже зареган то пропускаем этот шаг.